# Extracting timeseries information from netcdf file using coordinates

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm trying to extract evapotrasnspiration data from a NetCDF file for a point on the grid with a given coordinates. However, when I try to get the indexed values, I get an error that the index is out of bounds. The dimensions of the coordinate data are what are confusing me. The outputs of 'ncdump' are as follows:

```
NetCDF dimension information:
    Name: x
        size: 656
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: 'm'
        axis: 'X'
        long_name: 'easting of British National Grid (BNG) coordinate system'
        standard_name: 'projection_x_coordinate'
        bounds: 'x_bnds'
    Name: y
        size: 1057
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: 'm'
        axis: 'Y'
        long_name: 'northing of British National Grid (BNG) coordinate system'
        standard_name: 'projection_y_coordinate'
        bounds: 'y_bnds'
    Name: time
        size: 31
        type: dtype('float64')
        units: 'days since 1961-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        calendar: 'gregorian'
        axis: 'T'
        standard_name: 'time'
        long_name: 'time in days since 1961-01-01 00:00:00 UTC'
        bounds: 'time_bnds'
    Name: bnds
        size: 2
        WARNING: bnds does not contain variable attributes
NetCDF variable information:
    Name: lat
        dimensions: ('y', 'x')
        size: 693392
        type: dtype('float64')
        long_name: 'latitude'
        standard_name: 'latitude'
        units: 'degrees_north'
    Name: lon
        dimensions: ('y', 'x')
        size: 693392
        type: dtype('float64')
        long_name: 'longitude'
        standard_name: 'longitude'
        units: 'degrees_east'
    Name: time_bnds
        dimensions: ('time', 'bnds')
        size: 62
        type: dtype('float64')
    Name: x_bnds
        dimensions: ('x', 'bnds')
        size: 1312
        type: dtype('float64')
    Name: y_bnds
        dimensions: ('y', 'bnds')
        size: 2114
        type: dtype('float64')
    Name: crsOSGB
        dimensions: ()
        size: 1
        type: dtype('int32')
        grid_mapping_name: 'transverse_mercator'
        longitude_of_central_meridian: -2.0
        false_easting: 400000.0
        false_northing: -100000.0
        latitude_of_projection_origin: 49.0
        scale_factor_at_projection_origin: 0.9996012717
        longitude_of_prime_meridian: 0.0
        semi_major_axis: 6377563.396
        inverse_flattening: 299.3249646
        projected_coordinate_system_name: 'OSGB 1936 / British National Grid'
        geographic_coordinate_system_name: 'OSGB 1936'
        horizontal_datum_name: 'OSGB_1936'
        reference_ellipsoid_name: 'Airy 1830'
        prime_meridian_name: 'Greenwich'
        EPSG_code: 'EPSG:27700'
        unit: 'm'
        towgs84: array([ 375., -111.,  431.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.])
    Name: pet
        dimensions: ('time', 'y', 'x')
        size: 21495152
        type: dtype('float32')
        _FillValue: -99999.0
        standard_name: 'water_potential_evaporation_amount'
        standard_name_url: 'http://vocab.nerc.ac.uk/standard_name/water_potential_evaporation_amount/'
        long_name: 'Potential evapotranspiration'
        units: 'kg m-2'
        coordinates: 'lon lat'
        grid_mapping: 'crsOSGB'
        actual_range: array([0.       , 1.7461436], dtype=float32)
        cell_methods: 'time: sum'
```

I created a dictionary for my given coordinates and then use netCDF4 module to read the file and then try to extract the data for the coordinates. This is what I've tried so far:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset  
import pandas as pd

nc_f = 'pet/chess-pe_pet_gb_1km_daily_20010101-20010131.nc'
nc_fid = Dataset(nc_f, 'r') #read file into a dataset

brora = {'name' : 'Brora', 'lon': -4.1317, 'lat' : 58.1171} #coordinates for target data

lons = nc_fid.variables['lon']
lats = nc_fid.variables['lat']
time = nc_fid.variables['time_bnds'][:]
pet = nc_fid.variables['pet'][:]

lons_idx = np.abs(lons - brora['lon']).argmin()
lats_idx = np.abs(lats - brora['lat']).argmin()
bpet = pet[:, lats_idx,lons_idx]
```

When I run the above, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[96], line 4
      2 lats_idx = np.abs(lats - brora['lat']).argmin()
      3 print(lats_idx,lons_idx)
----> 4 bpet = pet[:, lats_idx,lons_idx]
      5 #bpet

File /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py:3216, in MaskedArray.__getitem__(self, indx)
   3206 """
   3207 x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y]
   3208 
   3209 Return the item described by i, as a masked array.
   3210 
   3211 """
   3212 # We could directly use ndarray.__getitem__ on self.
   3213 # But then we would have to modify __array_finalize__ to prevent the
   3214 # mask of being reshaped if it hasn't been set up properly yet
   3215 # So it's easier to stick to the current version
-> 3216 dout = self.data[indx]
   3217 _mask = self._mask
   3219 def _is_scalar(m):

IndexError: index 600538 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1057
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own problem. I was getting thrown by the 'lat' and 'long' attributes, but what I really wanted were the 'x' and 'y' attributes. The latter of which are in EPSG 27700. So I converted the coords in my dictionary to the correct format and then:

```
lons = nc_fid.variables['lon']
lats = nc_fid.variables['lat']
```

to:

```
lons = nc_fid.variables['x']
lats = nc_fid.variables['y']
```

Then changed the last line of code to:

```
bpet = pet[:, lats_idx,lons_idx]
```

Now I have the time series data I was looking for.